# How to fix the "508 Resource Limit is reached" error in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, resources, limit

> 508 Resource Limit is reached - Wordpress

This error occurs again and again, and I can't post a single post without seeing this error:

> The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Note that, if you have done nothing disruptive to your site through strange resource consuming plugins or operations, this could be happen because some bad redirections. Check the database for `wp`, tables `wp_postmeta` column `meta_value`, and `wp_posts` field `guid`, for the last created records, for possible bad paths.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it happens when the number of processes exceeds the limits set by the hosting provider.

To avoid either we need to enhance the capacity by hosting providers or we need to check in the code whether any process takes longer time (like background tasks).

Comment: Make php/cgi scripts run shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Your server is imposing some resource limit that your site is hitting.  This is usually RAM, CPU, or INODES.

Ask your server administrator what the limits are and what it is you are hitting to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I've already encountered this error and this is the best solution I've found:

In your root folder (probably called public_html)please add this code to your .htaccess file...

REPLACE the 00.00.00.000 with YOUR IP address. If you don't know your IP address buzz over to What Is My IP - The IP Address Experts Since 1999

```
#By Marky WP Root Directory to deny entry for WP-Login & xmlrpc
<Files wp-login.php>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 00.00.00.000
    </Files>
<Files xmlrpc.php>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 00.00.00.000
    </Files>
```

In your wp-admin folder please add this code to your .htaccess file...

```
#By Marky WP Admin Folder to deny entry for entire admin folder
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 00.00.00.000
<Files index.php>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 00.00.00.000
    </Files>
```

From: https://www.quora.com/I-am-using-shared-hosting-and-my-I-O-usage-is-full-after-every-minute-What-is-this-I-O-usage-in-cPanel-How-can-I-reduce-it

Answer (score 0):

On my blog, the reason of this error is a plugin named **Broken Link checker**. This plugin has high resource usage from hosting, resulting in this error.

Check if a plugin on your installation is behaving similarly like this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to this problem a lot when developing my company's website using WordPress. Finally I found that it happened because me and my colleague update the website at the same time as well as we installed and activated many plugins that we did not use them. The solution for me was we update the website in different time and deactivated and uninstalled those plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are receiving a DDOS attack. Use a firewall like Cloudflare.
Or it could be a loophole in WordPress that takes the server memory. Try to update WordPress to the latest version and disable all plugins and see.